# PHP variable value to be string+function

Tags: php

Can I have something like this in PHP?

```
$variable = 'string' . function() . 'string';
```

I tried it but I can't see if it gives an error or if it works.
Thanks in advance!

P.S. function() would return a string

Comment: I don't understand why you can't see if it works... also, what do you think `substr`, `str_replace`, etc. are? Of course they can be used within strings, and of course they are functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

`$variable = 'string' . function() . 'string';`
 will work

There is no reason for its failure, but your function should not have any error.